# Regex for extracting text between Tags but not the tags

Tags: java, html, regex, tags, nodes

I have the following Text:

```
<Data>
    <xpath>/Temporary/EIC/SpouseSSNDisqualification</xpath>
    <Gist>AllConditionsTrue</Gist>
    <Template>
        <Text id="1">Your spouse is required to have a Social Security number instead of an ITIN to claim this credit.  This is based on the IRS rules for claiming the Earned Income Credit.</Text>
    </Template>
</Data>
<Data>
    <xpath>/Temporary/EIC/SpouseSSNDisqualification</xpath>
    <Gist>AllConditionsTrue</Gist>
    <Template>
        <Text id="1">Your spouse has the required Social Security number instead of an ITIN to claim this credit.  This is based on the IRS rules for claiming the Earned Income Credit.</Text>
    </Template>
</Data>
```

I would like to extract the data between the `xpath` tags but not the tags themselves.

**Output should be:**

`/Temporary/EIC/SpouseSSNDisqualification`

`/Temporary/EIC/SpouseSSNDisqualification`

This Regex seems to give me all the text including the `xpath` tags which I don't want:

`<NodeID>(.+?)<\/NodeID>`

**Edit:**

Here is my Java code but I am not sure if this would add value to my question:

```
    try {
        String xml = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<xpath>(.+?)<\\/xpath>");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(xml);

        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question will be much better if you also put the java code you tried

Comment: [Don't parse XML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2482744) (the answer says HTML but it's the same issue)

Comment: You did capture what you want using the `(xxx)` capture group, so just use it by calling `group(1)`. `group(0)` returns the entire matches pattern, not just the captured part. --- Though I do agree with @AlexHall: **Don't use regex to extract text from XML.** Use an XML parser.

Comment: @Andreas thanks using group 1 worked like a charm

Comment: You can also use XPath. Not a node name, but a method called XPath

Comment: Putting the tried code in the question raise the value a lot, so we only need to correct your code a bit, not making a code for your from scratch and posing a risk the code is not compatible with your code as a whole

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy. It's because you take all the result, not just the group 1 value.

```
String nodestr = "<xpath>/Temporary/EIC/SpouseSSNDisqualification</xpath>";
String regex = "<xpath>(.+?)<\/xpath>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(nodestr);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String tag_value = matcher.group(1); //taking only group 1
    System.out.println(tag_value); //printing only group 1
}
```

Comment: Don't escape the `/`. It has no meaning in a Java regex, so escaping is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks @Aminah Nuraini

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a look-ahead and a look-behind approach:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=<xpath>)(.*?)(?=</xpath>)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String group = matcher.group();
    System.out.println(group);
}
```

I believe that's a way cleaner approach.